# How to create a "check-in/check-out" system with timestamps?

Tags: python, html, django

I have an app that sort of works in a check-in/check-out manner. People just enter their ID, area, and click check in and it sends the timestamp to the db with their info. There is also a "check-out" button that currently does nothing. It's supposed to work so that, once the person fills the form and submits, it'll will either do one of these things:

1. Find the previous check in entry based on the ID and Area entered and update the check out from NULL to timestamp.
2. If the person forgot to previously check in, then it will create a new record with just the check out timestamp and the ID/Area.

I thought that trying to find the user by matching both ID AND Area would be better since the same person can check in/out of different areas several times a day so matching only by ID could generate the problem of the program updating the wrong field at one point.

**models.py**

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class StationNumber(models.Model):
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, help_text="Employee #", blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Time in", null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, help_text="Time out", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = StationNumber.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

I guess my question is more towards, how could I go about implementing something like this?

And, currently the check in automatically saves the timestamp upon submit, but it shouldn't change it when the check out area button in pressed because it would defeat it's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l_userID = int(<feed the user id>)
l_areaID = <feed the area id>
l_stationId  =<feed the station id>

l_objLogEntry = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=l_userID,\
                                                   work_area__id = l_areaID,\
                                                   station_number__id = l_stationId)\
                                           .exclude(time_out__isnull=True,\
                                                    time_out__exact='')
if len(l_objLogEntry) == 0:
    #no login entry
elif len(l_objLogEntry) == 1:
    #update the timestamp
elif len(l_objLogEntry) > 1:
    #multiple open entries, do whatever
```